# Laravel redirect specific file route

Tags: laravel, routes

I moved old website to Laravel and there are some routes that I want to redirect to new pages.

Using

```
Route::get('/templates', function () {
  return redirect('/projects');
});
```

works fine, but what I need is to redirect specific file route like this

```
Route::get('/templates/turtle.php', function () {
  return redirect('/projects/2');
});
```

and with this I get error "No input file specified."

I tried something like this:

```
Route::get('/templates/{file}', function ($file) {
  if ($file == 'turtle.php') return redirect('/projects/2');
});
```

but no go.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I thought you can't redirect or open php files like that in laravel.

Comment: could be, but thats silly restriction, i have links like that seeded all over internet and they would all became broken if i cant make it in laravel

Comment: No input file specified sounds like the request isn't even reaching Laravel, it sounds like your server is looking for an actual turtle.php file.  You may have an invalid web server setup for this.

Comment: If you comment out / remove the route and try going to the url do you still get the same error or does it just 404?

Comment: @RossWilsonsame error

Comment: @Devon I solved it by creating actual file and in it writing php redirection

Comment: @pera that's good but you really shouldn't have to.  If your web server is set up correctly for Laravel, it should be directing all non-existing file requests to Laravel.  So you must have an invalid rewrite rule or something.